# kableExtra: set table width on ioslides_presentation

Tags: r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am using kableExtra on a ioslides_presentation R markdown file.
The table however does not fit the width of the slide:

[image]

I am using the following code to generate the table:

```
library(kable)
library(kableExtra)
data %>% 
kable() %>% 
kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"),full_width = FALSE)
```

I've also tried the argument full_width = TRUE, but was not successful.

How can I force this to happen automatically?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that it is possible to add a scroll bar to the table. 
This can be done using the scroll_box function as follows:

```
library(kable)
library(kableExtra)
data %>% 
kable() %>% 
kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")) %>%
scroll_box(width = "100%")
```